# Palm Pre on Device Anywhere

Tags: mobile-phones, webos, palm-pre

I have developed a simple application for palm webOS. Now I have the ipk file with me, but I want to test it using [Device Anywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/). Is there any way by which I can install my app in their Palm Pre?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you're asking, but it sounds like you might want to check out the [PreCentral Homebrew area](http://www.precentral.net/homebrew-apps).  That should give you some good ideas about what's involved in installing an app only any Pre, not just one that's directly connected to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Palm virtual device lab at http://www.deviceanywhere.com/palm/welcome.htm.  If you sign up there, you'll get access to a number of Palm Pre devices.  If you publish your application using the "web only" distribution mode, you can then download it and install it to the virtual Pre without it going into the app catalog or having to go through Palm review.